# preciso saber como remove índices com pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, analise-de-texto

Estou usando a biblioteca Pandas para resolver um desafio aqui onde trabalho. A partir de uma tabela em xlsx, preciso organizar as informações nela contida. criando uma quebra de linha

(por exemplo:
produto codigo preço
x       123     30
y       45      90
)

o problema é que os ídices das colunas fica aparecendo e eu não sei coo faz para remover e deixar a visualizão mais limpa

a segui mostro como ta o códigp:

```
ttv_AS = tabela['TTV ASR NAD']  #preço
print(ttv_AS[:-1]) #ta funcioando nao altere
​
#ttv_AS_produto = tabela['Nome Prod'] #produto
#print(ttv_AS_produto[:-1]) #funciona nao altere
​
#ttv_AS_cod = tabela['Cód Prod'] #codigo do produto
#print(ttv_AS_cod[:-1]) #funcioa nao altere
​
#print (f'{ttv_AS_produto[:-1]} {ttv_AS_cod[:-1]} {ttv_AS[:-1]}')
```

o resultado está assim:
0       0.0
1      60.0
2      33.8
3      37.9
4      93.8
...
199    28.5
200     0.0
201     0.0
202     0.0
203     NaN
Name: TTV ASR NAD, Length: 204, dtype: float64

ps: usei comentarios no codigo porque estou resolvendo uma parte por vez

Answer (score 1):

Olá, segue um exemplo de como remover índices, o `index=False` remove os índices a esquerda, o `header=False` remove o cabeçalho.

```
import pandas as pd

id = date = time = ['a','b', 'c']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': id, 'Date': date, 'Hour': time})


#Se for ser passado para um excel:
df.to_excel('Sheet.xlsx', 'Sheet1', index=False, header=False)

df_semIndices= df.to_string(index=False, header=False)

print('COM:  ')
print(df)

print('SEM:  ')
print(df_semIndices)
```